# Terraform: cannot import Google VPC Network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm following the Terraform documentation in my endeavours. I had no problems with `import` (I imported VMs, etc.) until I faced the importing a `Google VPC` network.

I created a module:

```tf
resource "google_compute_network" "vpn-site" {                          
  project = "project1"                                             
  name = "vpn-site"                                                   
}
```

I created a `main.tf` elswhere:

```tf
...
module "vpn-site" {                                                   
  source = "../../../vpn-site"                               
}
...
```

I also tried not using a module and import this from the single `main.tf` file. The response I get is this:

```
import module.vpn-site.google_compute_network.vpn-site result: vpn-site: import module.vpn-site.google_compute_network.vpn-site (id: vpn-site): Terraform detected a resource with this ID doesn't
exist. Please verify the ID is correct. You cannot import non-existent
resources using Terraform import.
```

But this network exists -- I'm using it :) (I changed the name for obvious reasons). Am I doing something wrong?
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_network.html

K.

Comment: Are you sure that both network ID and Project ID are correct?

Comment: project id are set in provider ?

Comment: How did you solve this?